# picamera: how to create a custom `image_effect`?

Tags: camera

This question is about the [`picamera`](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera) python module.

The docs have information about applying a number of built-in so called [`image_effect`](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.image_effect)s in real time.

Does anyone have info on how to create a totally custom image effect? For example, if I want to completely change the color-map or apply some image processing algorithm like histogram equalization or some other real-time image enhancement.

Comment: i think that the image effects are built into the camera itself

Answer (score 1):

The image effects are built into the closed-source firmware and likely a low priority feature. All camara APIs and libraires interface with this firmware, which finally controls the camera. You can apply any post-processing you want with NumPy or Pillow yourself, though.